# How to find and replace contents of a bracket as it is in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to replace `drop:label key="key1"` with `s:label key="gettext('key1')"`

I was trying in find `drop:label key=("*")` and in replace with `s:label key="gettext('*')"` but it replaces it with actual * and not with key1 as I wish

Anyone with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Npp you have to escape the parenthesis in the replacement part:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- in the replace window:

Find what: `drop:label key="(.*?)"`
Replace with: `s:label key="gettext\('$1'\)"`

Make sure `Regular expression` is checked, then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about Notepad++, but if it uses normal regex, your pattern should be something like:

```
drop:label key=\"(.*)\"
```

And then your replacement something like:

```
s:label key="gettext\('$1'\)"
```

*Update*: updated replacement because Notepad++ seems to require escaping on the replacement

Comment: The problem with this is that the find will select till end of last double quotes present in line and hence correct find should be drop:label key=\"(.*?)\", still thanks for your quick response helped a lot.